# How can I get remainding text from incomplete forum page using System.Net.WebClient() API or Ajax API?

Tags: ajax, vb.net, dom-events, webclient

I have written a little program in VB.Net to extract all questions and answers posted by me on the worst Belgian forum for customers that is https://www.test-achats.be/communautes

To do the job, I use `System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString()` function to get HTML source page in a string. Then I analyze this string to find what I want.

```
Private Function DownloadString(sPage As String) As String
    Dim sSource As String = ""

    Do While True
        Try
            sSource = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(sPage)
            Exit Do
        Catch ex As Exception
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
        End Try
    Loop

    Return sSource
End Function
```

I use a loop because sometime, forum server return some errors. When this happens, I wait 10 second and I continue until I receive a correct response.

My program work perfectly well ... except for some long pages as following page

https://www.test-achats.be/communautes/communication-multimedia/communication-multimedia-varia/conversation/3487/la-fin-de-la-fm

My problem is that `DownloadString()` function return only the 20 firsts user's comments.

On Chrome, to see the remainding comment, I must scroll until end of page to show <kbd>VOIR PLUS</kbd> button (= `SHOW MORE` in English).

[image]

I don't must click on this button, I must only scroll to end of page and automatically, the following 20 next user's comments are displayed following already displayed comments.

I have searched to understand Javascript mechanism hidden behind this special behavior, but I don't find how this is working.

Can somebody have a look on this `Test-Achats` page and explain how it is possible to simulate this event on a VB.Net console application?

The HTML code that contains this button is:

```
<div class="align-central">
    <button class="btn btn--secondary-alt js-bp-load-more" 
            rel="nofollow"
            data-selector="load_more_button">
voir plus
    </button>
</div>
```

I have continued to search and in searching all `load-more` string in html page, I have found following lines

```
</header>
<div class="js-browsepages" 
     data-load-more-url="/CommunitySitesAPI/CommunityConversationCommentOverview/LoadMore/0713953e-81d3-4e21-acdc-0bf01acab448?Contoller=CommunityConversationCommentOverview&amp;datasourceId=%7BBEA23CF6-77B3-4CA2-A7AD-9462180B8E15%7D&amp;threadId=3487&amp;replysort=cdd">
    <div class="js-bp-load-more-content">
    <div class="comment_item" 
         data-startreplyid="23399"
         data-islastreply="False" 
         data-selector="first_comment">
        <div class="comments-list__comment__container  "
             style="" 
             data-commentid="33205"
             data-selector="comment_container">
```

and using Developpement Tools on Chrome, in `Network` tab, when I scroll to end of page, I can see that following XLMHttpRequest is activated

```
Request URL: https://www.test-achats.be/CommunitySitesAPI/CommunityConversationCommentOverview/LoadMore/0713953e-81d3-4e21-acdc-0bf01acab448?Contoller=CommunityConversationCommentOverview&datasourceId=%7BBEA23CF6-77B3-4CA2-A7AD-9462180B8E15%7D&threadId=3487&replysort=cdd&type=&page=2&startReplyId=23399&isLastReply=False&_=1626368441484
```

From HTML page, I can then rebuild XMLHttpRequest, the only problem that I have now is

What represent last term (&_=1626368441484) in XMLHttpRequest and how can I get him ?

Comment: Think it might be achievable using WebView2.  Is there any API for test-achats that you could use which would in all likely hood be a much more robust solution

Comment: I have tought to use WebView2 but I search solution without using a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have follow my intuition and I have composed a XMLHttpRequest using data found in `<div class="js-browsepages">` without inserting last parameter without name (`&_`).

My test code is

```
Private Sub GetMultiCommentsPages()
    
    Dim sPage = "https://www.test-achats.be/communautes/communication-multimedia/communication-multimedia-varia/conversation/3487/la-fin-de-la-fm--trace-startup"
    Dim sSource = DownloadString(sPage)
    Dim sNewPage As String = "https://www.test-achats.be/"

    Dim iPos = 0
    Dim iEnd = 0
    Dim iPage = 2
    Dim sStartReplyId As String
    Dim sIsLastReply As String

    iPos = sSource.IndexOf("data-load-more-url=", iPos)
    iPos += 20
    iEnd = sSource.IndexOf("""", iPos)
    sNewPage &= sSource.Substring(iPos, iEnd - iPos)
    sNewPage = sNewPage.Replace("&amp;", "&")

    iPos = iEnd
    iPos = sSource.IndexOf("data-startReplyId=""", iPos)
    iPos += 19
    iEnd = sSource.IndexOf("""", iPos)
    sStartReplyId = sSource.Substring(iPos, iEnd - iPos)

    iPos = iEnd
    iPos = sSource.IndexOf("data-isLastReply=""", iPos)
    iPos += 18
    iEnd = sSource.IndexOf("""", iPos)
    sIsLastReply = sSource.Substring(iPos, iEnd - iPos)

    sNewPage &= "&type="
    sNewPage &= "&page=" & CStr(iPage)
    sNewPage &= "&startReplyId=" & sStartReplyId
    sNewPage &= "&isLastReply=" & sIsLastReply

    Dim sNewSource = DownloadString(sNewPage)
End Sub
```

At end of subroutine, `sNewSource` variable contains following user's comments.

I must now integrate last received comments with first one ad continue to read remainding comments using same technics.